# easier to use ratio test than comparison on this problem

Tags: calculus

Im trying to show $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-k^2} $

First, I was trying to bound $e^{-n^2}$ by using $e^x \geq x + 1$ so $$e^{x^2} \geq x^2 + 1 > x^2 \implies e^{-x^2} < \frac{1}{x^2} $$

and the convergence follows easily. I also tried the ratio test:

$$ \frac{ e^{-(k+1)^2} }{e^{-k^2}} = \frac{e^{-k^2-2k-1}  }{e^{-k^2}} = e^{-2k-1} \to 0 <1 $$

and thus the ratio test gives us convergence. Do you think it is easier using ratio than comparison?

Comment: I think they're both pretty easy. What is the point of your question? Just to gather opinions?

Comment: In general, comparison is easier than ratio test since there is a lot of stuff on the denominator in some cases.

Comment: @T.Bongers, "What is the point of your question? Just to gather opinions?"
Also to give some participants an easy way to self-assert.

Comment: @avs Sorry, what? I don't understand your last.

Comment: @T.Bongers, just a bit of friendly sarcasm.  Disregard, since you've shown understanding for the Asker.

Answer (score 1):

I would still use the comparison test:
$$
e^{-k^2} \leq 3^{-k^2} \leq 3^{-k}.
$$

Comment: Why even bother with messing around with the base? $e^{-k^2} \le e^{-k}$.

Comment: Purely psychological: on the possibility that the Asker may be new to the constant $e$ and not as fluent in estimating it.  (And, yes, I have seen such situations arise when I taught.)

Comment: I see, fair enough.